# Rails calling include custom Helpers, presenters hang in sidekiq external gem execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

In order to generate PDFs I Use a custom gem and call it In a sidekiq worker during thre process I call this initilizer:

```
From: /Users/toni/.rbenv/versions/2.4.9/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/bundler/gems/forest-ui-23f91ee3fbe9/lib/forest_pdf/generator.rb:7 ForestPdf::Generator#initialize:

     3: def initialize(template, theme, options = {})
     4:   @template = template
     5:   @theme = theme
     6:
 =>  7:   @av = ActionView::Base.new
     8:   @av.view_paths = ActionController::Base.view_paths
     9:   @av.class_eval { include Rails.application.helpers }
    10:   @av.instance_eval do
    11:     options.each { |k, v| instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) }
    12:   end
    13: end
```

The problem is that calling the worker in the console works generating the pdf, but this hangs:

```
Rails.application.helpers
```

Also this works:

[3] pry(#ForestPdf::Generator)> @av.class.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
=> ActionView::Base

and this:

```
[6] pry(#<ActionView::Base>):1> @av.class.include ActionController::Helpers
=> NilClass
```

But when I call a custom Helper

```
[7] pry(#<ActionView::Base>):1> @av.class.include Forest::ForestHelper
```

It also works when I require:

```
[6] pry(#<CyberPdf::Generator>)> require 'forest/forest_helper'
=> true
[7] pry(#<ForestPdf::Generator>)> @av.class.include Forest::ForestHelper
=> ActionView::Base
```

but hangs again requiring the presenters:

```
[9] pry(#<CyberPdf::Generator>)> require 'cyberthreats/threat_presenter'
```

It hangs, I do not know how to load this. when rendering the view I need the presenter methosd of this class. This code worked in rails 4, works when I executed the code in the rails console, but not executed inside sidekiq

Comment: It just hangs, no errors or anything?

Comment: it just hangs, two hours waiting and nothing

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with eager load vs autoload in Rails 5, After adding this to the config (application.rb) it worked:

```
config.eager_load = true
```

So you can put it only for your sidekiq using the boolean function `Sidekiq.server?`